# Ubuntu 18 LTS, Upgrade Processor may affect Operating System?

Tags: amd-processor, motherboard

I had build new CPU with

## Keep Motherboard Same

GIGABYTE GA-A320M-S2H AMD A320 AM4 MAX-32GB DDR4 Micro ATX PCIE16

## Processor Replacement:

AMD Ryzen 3 2200G with Radeon Vega 8 Graphics Desktop Processor 4 Cores up to 3.7GHz 6MB Cache AM4 Socket (YD2200C5FBBOX)

Now I had bought "AMD Ryzen 7 2700" Octa Core new processor, like to replace

## Problem Domain

Do I need to reinstall ubuntu operating system in case I change processor only ?

Note: Correct in case I explain wrong way.

Answer (score -1):

## Ubuntu Auto Check

Some people in forum indicate hardware auto check when boot and according it accept, so no need reinstallation of ubuntu.

## Kernel!

Some people indicates due to kernel is tidy with hardware, so reinstall required.

## Opinion

I found linux/ubuntu new upgrade of kernel auto managed hardware do all stuff and on operating system boot up / restart it automatically organize.

Yes. without reinstall CPU can be change, just power off and replace CPU and reboot operating system will works.

Comment: With nagative mark, least give confident comment. Please